# how to spinmap in Python?

Tags: python, matlab

How can i make a similar work with Python ? A example described how does "spinmap" work with MATLAB language is given as follows.

### matlab code

1. sphere;
2. axis equal;
3. axis off;
4. spinmap(20,1);

Answer (score 0):

`spinmap` does nothing other than cyclically shifting the colormap. You can achieve the same effect with the following MATLAB code:

```
sphere;
axis equal off
cmap=colormap;

for i=1:200
    colormap(cmap(circshift(1:64,[0,-i]),:));
    drawnow
end
```

This must be easy to implement in python. I'll leave it to someone who knows python better than I do to translate it idiomatically.